# How to respond dynamically by using File Containing Templates?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, cpp, spiffs

We are developing a Web Console and REST API for the NodeMCU V3 ESP8266, using `ESPAsyncWebServer`. We are facing some difficulties to serve dynamic pages using File Containing Templates! We're unable to replace `REQ_HOST_ID` with `request->host()` using Template Processor! The following code is working fine when a static host name is supplied.

```
// server->on("/", HTTP_GET, HomePage::index);

void HomePage::index(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println(request->host());
    auto processor = [](const String &var) -> String {
        if (var == "REQ_HOST_ID"){
        //  return F(request->host()); //FIXME
            return F("10.10.10.1"); 
        }
        return String();
    };
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(SPIFFS, "/www/index.html", String(), false, processor);
    response->addHeader("Server", "Academia Web Server");
    request->send(response);
}
```

**Edited:**

Commented code causes a compile-time error and needs to be fixed to set the value of `request->host()`. `request->host().c_str()` causes the same error!

```
/Users/Chorke/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AcademiaCoreWeb/src/pages/HomePage.cpp: In lambda function:
/Users/Chorke/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AcademiaCoreWeb/src/pages/HomePage.cpp:16:22: error: 'request' is not captured
             return F(request->host()); //FIXME
                      ^
/Users/Chorke/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/cores/esp8266/WString.h:38:76: note: in definition of macro 'FPSTR'
 #define FPSTR(pstr_pointer) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(pstr_pointer))
                                                                            ^
/Users/Chorke/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.6.3/cores/esp8266/WString.h:39:34: note: in expansion of macro 'PSTR'
 #define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))
                                  ^
/Users/Chorke/Documents/Arduino/libraries/AcademiaCoreWeb/src/pages/HomePage.cpp:16:20: note: in expansion of macro 'F'
             return F(request->host()); //FIXME
```

Your help resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Buggy in which way?

Comment: `return F(request->host());` causes compile time error! Need to fix this and it belonging  issues. It's suppose to be there is two issue 1. `request` not accessible inside lambda expression and 2. **directly belongs to the data type conversion**

Comment: A compiler error is not a bug... please include the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
auto processor = [request](const String &var) -> String {
    if (var == "REQ_HOST_ID"){
        return request->host().c_str();
    }
    return String();
};
```

Two mistake causes compile time error:

1. Needs to pass `request` to the `Lambda` expression
2. Need not to wrap the dynamic value with `F()` macro